# Android permission to limit INSTALL_REFERRER to play store

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm setting up campaign tracking using custom analytics (not google analytics) and setting up a receiver for that. My receiver seems to be working, but when I install I get an android lint warning:

```
ExportedReceiver: Receiver does not require permission
```

It looks like any old android app could call my application with the `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` intent which I do not want. It should only be the Google Play Store (or any other android system application that would install my app from the play store) sending that intent to my application.

So I've tried to figure out how to set up a permission that limits the valid applications to the play store, but I can't figure out the correct way to set up the permission according to the documentation:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

Could someone help me setup a permission that limits the applications my application will accept this intent from to the play store? Here's my current receiver config:

```
    <receiver
            android:name=".referrals.MyCampaignTrackingReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I tried setting a permission for the receiver at the `normal` level but that prevented the app from receiving the intent from the playstore.

Comment: Why are you so worried about this receiver permission? Assuming you know you need to handle this broadcast only once, right after install, and you take measures to handle it only once, an attacker will have to know when your app has been installed and somehow send this broadcast before the playstore app. Seems highly unlikely to me.

Comment: @Yoni Gross Honestly, I hadn't considered ensuring it could only be called once, which would probably be beneficial anyway.

Comment: @YoniGross If you want to add your comment as an answer I'll make it the accepted answer since it is what I am actually doing in my app. I gave the bounty to ozbek because he actually answered the question, but your suggest is better for me.

Comment: Actually @ozbek answer seems simpler, and a better answer to your question. Yet, I would have used the `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission, which seems more appropriate.

Comment: @YoniGross I think it would be difficult to test if I used his solution, because my test methods don't have that permission. Also, we have reason to want to track the number of times this is called (a single user could reinstall due to multiple sources), so I didn't do exactly what you suggested, but it inspired me to do something better for our app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INSTALL_REFERRER broadcast permission is not a great concern. Assuming you know you need to handle this broadcast only once, right after install, and you take measures to handle it only once, an attacker will have to know when your app has been installed and somehow send this broadcast before the playstore app, which seems unlikely.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set [`android:permission`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html#prmsn) attribute on your receiver. So that it will look something like this:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".referrals.MyCampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Usage of [`"android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CLEAR_APP_CACHE) here is arbitrary, you can use any permission that Play Store has AND is *not possible* for third-party apps to have (because `CLEAR_APP_CACHE`s protection level is `system|signature` only system apps or apps signed with the same certificate as the application that declared this permission; in this case the platform). For example, [looking through](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) Play Store's manifest suggests, `"com.android.vending.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"` could be another good candidate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to test this out yet, but what you describe makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

3rd party apps can not broadcast this intent. It is blocked. And permission to send is only granted to system apps.
[image]
[image]